# animateWithDuration android equivalent

Tags: android, animation

IOS code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

**What is the equivalent of android?**

i'm searching but only found [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html), and is not clear for me.

i try using :

```
view.animate().x(myxVal);
```

> But i need move many elements and with `IOS animateWithDuration` can do it without problems.

any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can call animate() on multiple views. So it is possible to move multiple elements at the same time. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @FierceFox With `animate()` i can't move some things. For example `setScrollX` in scrollview, i'm trying with `ObjectAnimator` but the result not are the same like ios